# What can i expect in the debug log when i run a visualforce page with input parameters to Canvas app?

Tags: canvas, debug

I built a visualforce page with the canvas app. The visualforce page contains only the canvas app and no other data related stuff. The canvas app is based on SAP webdynPro. I am also passing three parameters to the canvas app. After running the vf page, i checked the debug log for some kind of detailed information like,

1. type of request that canvas app used.
2. the parameters that is being passed to canvas app.

But the debug log looks very simple and plain just like the one given below.

```
29.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
08:33:01.030 (30574000)|EXECUTION_STARTED
08:33:01.030 (30622000)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|06690000004PcxZ|VF: /apex/sapcanvaswithinput
08:33:01.629 (87437000)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
08:33:01.629|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 10
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of fields describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of record type describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of child relationships describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of picklist describes: 0 out of 100
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 10
```

**Question:**

1. Is the above debug log a normal one for a canvas app or should it contains more details?
2. How and where can i verified what parameters has been passed over to the canvas app?

**Update:**

[image]

Thanks,
Baskaran

Comment: Did you set your debug log levels to "finest"?

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I changed the log level in developer console for visualforce to finest and still it is emitting the same log. Please see the screen shot above. Also, if i checked the debug log level in developer console again the log level reverts back to INFO for visualforce. Is that something i am missing here? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canvas framework does not hook into the VF developer console.

To do any debugging, you can open a developer console (chrome) or firebug (firefox) and look at the data being passed over the network and through JavaScript.